# Recommended locations to store app licence file and database?

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

Where would the recommended location be to store an app licence file and a SQLite database for Android? Also, what are the constants used to point to those locations?

Note that the location(s) must be accessible without having to root the device, so the app data folder is not an option. I need to be able to access the files via a PC using a standard file manager.

I noticed that on the root folder of the device, there is a folder called "db" where other apps seem to store data. Is that a good location to store my db? If so, what is the Environment constant that points to it?

Comment: By `app data folder`, what do you mean? Internal Storage? Do you want your licence file and .db file to be uninstalled when user uninstalled your App? If don't, you need put them on External Storage( like @ Sotiris  has clarified), else you can put them on Internal Storage.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the level of security you want to achieve, there are numerous approaches to this issue.

At it's simplest you could store them at any folder on you external storage(Documents,Downloads e.t.c) or on your SD card provided that the user has given you permission AND has himself selected the path since newer Android Versions have reworked(restricted) the way an app can read/write from/to an SD card.

If for example you want to store it to "documents" folder you could do the following:

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS),".dir");
```

This selects the "Documents"  folder and creates a folder called dir. Note the "." before "dir" , meaning that the folder will be invisible as a first level of security. From here on you can create any number of directories or files you desire.

Comment: I am targeting a specific Android device that has a lot of internal storage space, so I do not need to access external storage. Where would be the best place within the internal storage to save my licence and db files?

Comment: Or is this not possible? Can an app only write to its own data folder when accessing internal storage?

Comment: Android naming conventions are a bit strange so let me clarify this first:

-Internal Storage = The disk space allocated to your app. The app data folder if you wish.

-External Storage = Everything else on the disk apart from the app data folder

-SD card  != External Storage

Having said that, i cannot recommend a single place as being "best". The "best" would be to store your db on the internal storage as it is the most secure but i understand your restrictions.

Comment: If you do not want to select the "Directory" folder as i suggested in my answer, use the same command with "Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS" to choose the "downloads" folder, or "Environment.DIRECTORY_ALARMS" to choose the "alarms" folder and so on.